# What to do with "Fixed while Troubleshooting" questions?

Tags: discussion

Robert Barnes asked [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/20914/battery-light-wont-go-off-since-changing-battery?noredirect=1#comment37285_20914) a while back. I recently asked him if he was able to fix the issue. He stated in the comments that the problem went away after a while. This to me is a term I've heard in the computer realm called ***Fixed While Troubleshooting***.

Question: **How should these questions be dealt with?**

Should these just then be closed? Looking for comment and discussion.

Comment: It's more of a "fixed-after-carwash" in the case of that question, but I catch your drift :)

Answer (score 3):

### I think we should tag them

Something like [no-smoking-gun](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-smoking-gun) or [elusive-smoking-gun](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elusive-smoking-gun), perhaps?

Comment: I'm up for a ridiculous tag   :-)   we should have a few.

Comment: @DucatiKiller well, at least form follows function :D